# Timezone offset incorrect when add file to sharepoint library with hashtable and datetime field

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, timezone

Don't ask me why, but i need to upload file and set of metadata with one action(Files.Add() and Update() after does not a fit).

I use this code to upload file with metadata:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       using (var site = new SPSite("http://shp2013:4000"))
       {
          using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
          {
             var list = web.Lists["TheLibrary"];

             var dt = new DateTime(2011,1,11, 18, 15, 00);
             var dtUtc = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToUniversalTime(dt);
             var ht = new Hashtable();
             ht.Add("TheDate", dtUtc);
             var file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add("filename.bin", new byte[]{ 1,5,12 }, ht, overwrite: true);
             var theDate = file.Item["TheDate"];

             Console.WriteLine("Original date: {0}", dt);
             Console.WriteLine("Original in UTC: {0}",dtUtc);
             Console.WriteLine("Value get: {0}", theDate);
          }       
       }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Original date: 1/11/2011 6:15:00 PM
Original in UTC: 1/11/2011 3:15:00 PM
Value get: 1/11/2011 7:15:00 PM
```

And that is the problem:

The value of  variable **theDate** :

In w3wp.exe:

**2011-01-11 18:15:00.000**  (good)

In console application:

**2011-01-11 19:15:00.000**  (incorrect)

At input **dtUtc** contains same value.

Why console app timezone offset is different than in w3wp?
What i need check: ThreadCulture, ThreadUICulture or something else?

Because this is a part of shared framework, code must run in a different environments, with any OS settings.

**Background**:

Sharepoint regional settings:

- locale: 'russian'
- time zone: '(UTC+03:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd (RTZ 2)'

Windows server settings:

- display language: English(US)
- region format: English(US)
- Home location: Russia
- Language for non-unicode: English(US)

Comment: If the time zone is UTC+3, why is 18:15 correct? If you can produce a short but complete console app demonstrating the problem, could you do that? It would be good to get everything Sharepoint-related out of the picture. (It's not clear how the Hashtable is relevant either, to be honest...)

Comment: @JonSkeet, see the screenshot, provided code is complete. HashTable passed in Add() method.
I think that 18:15 is right because i set it, but i get back with +1 hour

Comment: Please don't post *screenshots* of code (not that that's complete anyway - it doesn't include a class declaration) - screenshots make it very hard for others to reproduce your results. Make your console app write out the relevant values, and show the output separately. I see why this is Sharepoint-specific now though...

Comment: What is `list` in this code? (Bear in mind I have no sharepoint experience, but you don't appear to be using `web` anywhere within the `using` statement...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, use SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime to set date. It solves many problems with Dates in SharePoint.